# FCM on iOS An error occured on client IDB480752 while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/4.8.0.752/stop-app

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I added firecloud messaging to my iOS app as described here https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/firebaseioscloudmessaging#subscribe-the-client-app-to-a-topic and it seems to work fine for both foreground and background notificaitons on initial run of the app. I am actually using the nuget Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging not the component.

When I open the app a second time after having sent at least one push notification I get this error at launch in the debug output.

**An error occured on client IDB480752 while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/4.8.0.752/stop-app**

Looking at the ide logs gives a little more detail.

*NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
2018-02-16 16:47:54.525 RecoveryConnect_Mobile_PCLiOS[1018:3202793]  Encounter network error. Code, error: -1200, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
    "",
    ""
), NSUnderlyingError=0x10b0f5190 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
    "",
    ""
)}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0}
The app has been terminated.
Failed to Stop app:  An error occured on client IDB480752 while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/4.8.0.752/stop-app
The app has been terminated.*

```cs
 public partial class AppDelegate : 
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate, 
    IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, IMessagingDelegate
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    global::Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init();
    App.BuildNumber = NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary[new 
    NSString("CFBundleVersion")].ToString();
    LoadApplication(new App());

    RegisterForPushNotifications();

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);

}

public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication uiApplication)
{
    //Messaging.SharedInstance.ShouldEstablishDirectChannel = false;
    Messaging.SharedInstance.Disconnect();
}

public override void OnActivated(UIApplication uiApplication)
{
    ConnectFCM();
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    base.OnActivated(uiApplication);
}




    private void RegisterForPushNotifications()
    {
        try
        {
            Firebase.Core.App.Configure();

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {
                // iOS 10 or later
                var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) => {
                    Console.WriteLine(granted);
                });

                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

                // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
                Messaging.SharedInstance.RemoteMessageDelegate = this;
            }
            else
            {
                // iOS 9 or before
                var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
                var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
            }

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

            Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.Notifications.ObserveTokenRefresh((sender, e) =>
            {
                var newToken = Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token;

                var FCMTokenRegistration = new Models.Model_FCMToken(newToken);
                FCMTokenRegistration.StoreToken();
                // if you want to send notification per user, use this token
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newToken);

                ConnectFCM();
            });
        }
        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            Helpers.Helper_ErrorHandling.SendErrorToServer(ex);
        }



    }

    private void ConnectFCM()
    {
        Messaging.SharedInstance.Connect(error => {
            if (error != null)
            {
                // Handle if something went wrong while connecting
            }
            else
            {
                // Let the user know that connection was successful
            }
        });

    }

    public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired 'till the user taps on the notification launching the application.

        // Do your magic to handle the notification data
        System.Console.WriteLine(userInfo);
    }

    // To receive notifications in foreground on iOS 10 devices.
    [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        // Do your magic to handle the notification data
        System.Console.WriteLine(notification.Request.Content.UserInfo);
    }

    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
    public void ApplicationReceivedRemoteMessage(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(remoteMessage.AppData);
    }

    [Export("userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
    {
        // Do your magic to handle the notification data
        System.Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    public void DidRefreshRegistrationToken(Messaging messaging, string fcmToken)
    {

        var token = fcmToken;
        //var newToken = Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token;

        //var FCMTokenRegistration = new Models.Model_FCMToken(newToken);
        //FCMTokenRegistration.StoreToken();
        //// if you want to send notification per user, use this token
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newToken);

        //ConnectFCM();
    }
```

I did try adding NSAppTransportSecurity for arbitrary loads with no avail.

Comment: You didn't do anything in `DidReceiveRemoteNotification()`, `WillPresentNotification()`, `DidReceiveNotificationResponse()`, then when you receive the notification, the app will crash?

Comment: The crash is not coming from any of those events. I placed a try catch around all of them with a system level exception catch and nothing is thrown.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solution or workaround?

Comment: @RenzoCiot If I recall the issue was related to the generated GoogleService-Info.plist from firebase not actually having all the proper fields filled in. It was so long ago I cannot remember exactly what they were but you should do a comparison between yours and what the docs say it should look like... think things like GCM_Sender_ID or Google_APP_ID were not present from the generated file.